# Webview in Windows 8 metro apps using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, webview, microsoft-metro

I'm currently working on a Windows 8 metro app (javascript, HTML5) which is supposed to display a specific website in a separate webview. Unfortunately, I have not found any description of how to add a web view to the app. Would you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Webviews are not available for WinJS. However, you can use `iframe` as an alternative. But, not all websites can be embedded in `iframe`s.

```
<iframe src=""></iframe>
```